# ORMLite store all class fields annotation

Tags: java, ormlite

Recently, I use ORMLite and I found that ORMLite's `@DatabaseField` annotation have `persisted` value 
([link](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#persisted())).

> Set this to be false (default true) to not store this field in the database. This is useful if you want to have the annotation on all of your fields but turn off the writing of some of them to the database.

That documentation note suggest that there is way to have annotation on all of class fields.
Does ORMLite have any annotation which provides 'store all fields' feature?
Or there is another way to do that instead adding @DatabaseField to every field in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does ORMLite have any annotation which provides 'store all fields' feature? Or there is another way to do that instead adding @DatabaseField to every field in class.

Sorry but no it doesn't.   There is no way using annotations to have all field be persisted.  There are other ways to [configure a class](http://ormlite.com/docs/class-config) in ORMLite but none that will automatically add details about all fields.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Now I see one purpose of using `@DatabaseField(persisted=false)` instead simply removing it, namely keeping some code style. Is there any other reason to use `persisted=false` value?

Comment: Not really.  I think people wanted to see `@DatabaseField` annotation on all fields and just turn the persisted flag on and off.  I don't use it actually @obywatelgcc.